# Is a battery a reasonable model for a forward biased diode? Why are the knee voltages different in the below Multisim schematics?

Tags: diodes, multisim, graph

Here are two DC sweeps from Multisim.

One ranges from 0 to 15 mA and the other 0 to 50 uA. They are different.

What battery voltage should be used to model a silicon diode?

Ultimately, my question is: what battery voltage should we use to model a silicon diode?

[image: Circuit used in schematic]

[image: 0 to 15 mA IV characteristic]

[image: 0 to 50 uA IV characteristic]

Comment: The curves are not different. If you adjust the scale on the first one to be the same as the second one, they will be the same.

Comment: What do you mean "adjust the scale"?

Comment: graph number 2 goes from 0 uA to 50 uA. If you "zoom in" on graph number 1 by only showing from 0 uA to 50 uA, it will be identical to graph number 2. The graphs are not different.

Answer (score 2):

*Is a battery a reasonable model for a forward-biased diode?*
Well, that's an engineering question: what is reasonable and what is not. I'd add one more component that might help decide reasonablness - a resistor. Then you have a Thevenin equivalent for your voltage source (a two-component circuit you should become very familiar with).

Your top plot examines the diode at 0.7V, where approx 5.5mA flows. The slope \$\Delta V\over\Delta I\$ at that point is roughly 20 ohms.

Your bottom plot examines the diode at 0.55V, where approx 17uA flows. The slope \$\Delta V\over\Delta I\$ at that point is roughly 7k ohms.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgNZ3B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You *must* ensure that current always flows if you intend the diode to act as a voltage source. The worst case happens when instantaneous current falls to its lowest level  - that's where diode equivalent resistance rises.
Another thing to consider: Diode voltage varies with temperature

Ideally, you want a voltage source to have zero resistance, so that varying current flowing through it doesn't affect its voltage. You might compare this diode model's internal resistance to the resistances external to its two terminals:

### If the diode model's internal resistance is considerably *less than* external resistance, it might be considered a reasonable voltage source.

If internal resistance is >= external resistance, then the diode might be biased with more DC current (which will lower its internal resistance) to improve the situation. Remember though, that more bias current will also increase the model's voltage, and will generate heat.
That DC bias current must come from somewhere. Biasing with a current source as OP's test circuit is the ideal way. Biasing with a resistor is less-ideal, because the bias resistor is considered along with "external" resistance, and will likely make your internal/external decision less-ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The "knee" moves to a different voltage because the scale of the chart changed.  If you were to plot it on a log scale, the mechanics would be more clear.

Using the simpler V-R piecewise linear model, you'd estimate the V based on the current you expect under normal operation.  The R can be determined by estimating the slope of the plot above the knee.

Comment: What do you mean "the scale of the chart changed"?

Comment: Look at the numbers on the vertical axis. The lower graph has numbers 3 orders of magnitude smaller than the other graph. Now take the lower graph and make it "fit" on the higher graph: it becomes squished vertically so much that it looks like a horizontal line.